# Upgraded to Windows 10 and now I can't access TrueCrypt partition

Tags: windows-10, truecrypt

I have upgraded to Windows 10 and now I can't access the TrueCrypt partition anymore. Now I know I should have decrypted --> upgraded ---> encrypted but now it's too late.

I can't seem to find the rescue disk for TrueCrypt (what is the file xtension btw?).

If I go back to windows 8.1 should I be able to read the partition again?

Thanks a lot,

Comment: TrueCrypt stores an .iso copy of the rescue disk on your system

Comment: No; You still won't be able to read it even if you roll back.

Comment: If you roll back *completely* to a previous system image, you *should* be able to access the partition. Then, as you state, decrypt and save it.

Comment: Encryption keeps your data safe by rendering it unusable if tampering operations like this occur. It is the responsibility of the user to learn how to properly back up encrypted data, keys, partition headers, etc. **before** implementing anything that messes with partition tables or modifies the encryption software used to protect the drive/data. Data loss is the intended function of encryption and recovery afterwards is intended to be impossible. Welcome to plausible deniability.